# Intuitive way to handle variable binding

Tags: pl.programming-languages, lambda-calculus, functional-programming

Suppose we have an algebraic datatype parameterised by a type variable `name`, e.g.

```
data Prog name = Var name
               | App (Prog name) (Prog name)
               | Abs name (Prog name)
               deriving (Show, Eq)
```

What is the most straightforward and intuitive way to handle bindings and substitutions? Specifically, I am hoping for something that only relies on the type parameter (`name`) so that the underlying algebraic datatype doesn't need to be altered (unlike, for example, De Bruijn index). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion does not quite work, but **polymorphic higher-order abstract syntax** does:

```
data Prog name = Var name
               | App (Prog name) (Prog name)
               | Abs (name -> Prog name)
```

See the paper [Parametric Higher-Order Abstract Syntax for Mechanized Semantics](http://adam.chlipala.net/papers/PhoasICFP08/PhoasICFP08.pdf) by Adam Chlipala.